# Javascript touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, touch

Hey! Just checkin in to see if there's a function similar to js onmousemove (jquery mousemove) for touch phones? Seems like jQuery mobile doesn't have it and I'm pretty new to all this with mobiles.

/tn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [jQuery UI for iPad and iPhone](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/) project. It supports [Android too](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/issues/detail?id=5).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$(element).bind('touchmove', function(){

});
```

in jQuery-less javascript, it is ontouchmove.

If you want to convert your current mouse events over to touch, just add this 'touch punch' plugin:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score -1):

This is very close to what I was looking for:
http://swipejs.com/